# How to catch the Exception thrown from file_get_contents() in PHP?

Tags: php, file, exception, file-io

Here's my code:

```
if(!$fileContents = file_get_contents($pathToXMLFile,true))
{
  throw new RuntimeException("Could not open .xml file");
}
```

I would like to catch this error as an Exception so that I can handle it appropriately. However, it seems that the script aborts before I get the change to catch it. Is there any workaround to this?

P.S.: When I try and do that, I only get a *faile to open stream. No such file or directory* error message.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm confused - if you want to catch the exception, why do you throw it in the first place? You could simply handle the issue within that block, and then throw a bigger exception when appropriate.

Comment: file_get_contents generates an E_WARNING instead of exception. You can suppress it with `@file_get_contents(...` then get an error with `error_get_last`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will convert all errors, warnings and notices to exceptions:

```
function exceptions_error_handler($severity, $message, $filename, $lineno) {
  if (error_reporting() == 0) {
    return;
  }
  if (error_reporting() & $severity) {
    throw new ErrorException($message, 0, $severity, $filename, $lineno);
  }
}
set_error_handler('exceptions_error_handler');
```